# Oracle Provider Link for SQL Server 2019 Developer

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I have just set up a new Virtual Machine 64 Bit and have installed Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition 64 Bit.

I am wanting to set up a linked server to an Oracle database Version 18.4.0.376.
Unfortunately I have done this in the past locally but cannot remember the version/download location of the Oracle Data Access Components that I need to give me the OraOLEDB.Oracle "SQL Provider" to make this work.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Oracle 18c client and setup linked server.

You can find oracle 18c client and all other oracle installations related to Oracle in Windows in the below link:

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle18c-windows-180000-downloads.html